# How to hide table rows without resizing overall width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, html-table

Is there a way to hide table rows without affecting the overall table width? I've got some javascript that shows/hides some table rows, but when the rows are set to `display: none;`, the table with shrinks to fit the contents of the visible rows.

Comment: Linking to [question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807564/hiding-a-tr-while-still-involving-it-in-width-calculations) for anyone looking for a modern solution: all relevant browsers support `visibility: collapse` (for rows and columns) which is specifically designed for that use case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking to preserve the overall width of the table, you can check it prior to hiding a row, and explicitly set the width style property to this value:

```
table.style.width = table.clientWidth + "px";
table.rows[3].style.display = "none";
```

However, this may cause the individual columns to reflow when you hide the row. A possible way to mitigate this is by adding a style to your table:

```
 table {
  table-layout: fixed;
 }
```

Comment: ...until you resize the window, then the table's fixed width doesn't reflow any more, because it's now a fixed pixel width...

Comment: I using table-layout: fixed; and my problem go away :D

Answer (score 9):

CSS rule [`visibility: collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#Values) was designed exactly for that.

```css
tbody.collapsed > tr {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

After adding this CSS you could trigger visibility from JS with:

```
tbody.classList.toggle('collapsed');
```

Comment: This definitely seems like the best answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, levik's solution works perfectly. In my case, using jQuery, the solution looked something like this:

```
$('#tableId').width($('#tableId').width());
```

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, `table-layout: fixed;` on your table instructs the browser to honor the sizes you've specified for heights and widths.  This generally suppresses auto-resizing by the browser unless you haven't given any hints as to the preferred sizes of your rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using pure HTML

```html
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="150px" />
    <col width="10px"  />
    <col width="220px" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">1</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```